# NodeJS 0.10.46 not serving after lighttpd proxy anymore

Tags: node.js, lighttpd

today I've updated my nodejs installation (from official CentOS 7 repo).

I used to serve via a lighttpd proxy, nothing special:

```
proxy.server = ( "" =>
                     ( "" =>
                       (
                         "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                         "port" => 2368,
                       )
                     )
                   )
```

NodeJS itself is working fine, I got two apps running well (if accessed directly), lighttpd also proxying a third app (provided by a Java runtime), that's full functional.

Problem started with NodeJS update to 0.10.46 (via yum package manager), changed nothing on my configuration.

Lighttpd proxy.debug output:

```
(mod_proxy.c.1158) proxy - start
(mod_proxy.c.1199) proxy - ext found
(mod_proxy.c.1333) proxy - found a host 127.0.0.1 2368
(mod_proxy.c.417) connect delayed: 11
(mod_proxy.c.1042) proxy: fdevent-out 1
(mod_proxy.c.1065) proxy - connect - delayed success
(mod_proxy.c.1030) proxy: fdevent-in 4
(mod_proxy.c.652) proxy - have to read: 0
(mod_proxy.c.1158) proxy - start
(mod_proxy.c.1199) proxy - ext found
(mod_proxy.c.1333) proxy - found a host 127.0.0.1 2368
(mod_proxy.c.417) connect delayed: 11
(mod_proxy.c.1042) proxy: fdevent-out 1
(mod_proxy.c.1065) proxy - connect - delayed success
(mod_proxy.c.1030) proxy: fdevent-in 4
(mod_proxy.c.652) proxy - have to read: 0
```

NodeJS output:

```
"GET / HTTP/1.0" 
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 200
```

So request is forwarded in first step, but then only a

> 500 - Internal Server Error

is delivered by lighttpd.

Any ideas? Don't know what I can try anymore.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're running lighttpd 1.4.40 or 1.4.41, then you're probably tripping over a known bug (https://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/2744) (sorry).  The bug is fixed in lighttpd git master and will part of lighttpd 1.4.42 with ETA next month, mid October 2016.

Comment: @gstrauss You were right: After update to lighttpd 1.4.43 it works again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First comment to question was the right hint: 
lighttpd version were problematic, update to 1.4.43 was the solution.

Comment: You may want to elaborate more on what you did, for future people's help.

Answer (score 0):

## Node Version

Firstly I'd like to also point out that nodejs 0.10.x is very out of date.  NodeJS is currently on v4.5 LTS and v6.5 Current. As the Javascript world moves very rapidly, relying on your distro's packages can leave you stuck with a very old version of node. You can use the nodesource.com service to get a recent build for your system. For example.

```
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
yum install -y nodejs
```

## Issues to check first

With that out of the way is your NodeJS application available at localhost:2368 ? Try accessing it in your browser (or a text browser like w3m if 2368 isn't open to the outside world). This could be as simple as NodeJS not returning data to the user.

Your lighttpd.conf looks fine however it is nested needlessly deep while this probably won't fix your issues try:

```
proxy.server = (
        "" => (
                (
                        "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                        "port" => "2368"
                )
        )
)
```

## Other Possibilities

While I can't know exactly what your system is doing, I would assume this is more likely to be a node issue than a lighty issue. Try writing a simple http server hello world application in node and see if that is available to proxy.

Comment: Thank you a lot, unfortunately a nodejs update to 4.5 did not change anything. I did not copy the whole lighttpd config, the proxy matches just one url pattern, that's why it's nested deeply. Before the "new" nodejs version (0.10.46) was delivered from the CentOS repository the configuration worked well.